# Can't set scoped variable in $.post callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, scope

I have the following type of structure:

```
(function(){

var objects = [];

$('button.one').on('click', function(){

  fetchObjects = function(objects) {
    $.post("/fetchObjects")
      .done(function(data){
        objects = data;
        console.log(objects.length);
      });
  }
  fetchObjects(objects)

});

$('button.two').on('click', function(){
  console.log(objects.length);
});

})();
```

You can see I have a variable `objects` that is local to this function. Initially its empty. When I click `button.one` I wish to populate `objects` with the returned value from some ajax request. It appears to work, however when clicking `button.two`, the `objects` variable is still an empty array.

Why isn't `objects` available in the jQuery callback?

I've also tried this approach but with the same results:

```
function callback(data) {
  facilities = data
}

$.post("/fetchObjects")
.done(function(data){
  callback(data);
});
```

What am I missing here? Please don't tell me to make "objects" global.

Comment: `objects = data` doesn't change the original `objects` variable.

Comment: why are you passing objects as a parameter? wouldn't it be easier to access it directly?

Comment: `objects = data` is not accessing it directly? If not, how do I access it directly? @Juhana I know. What the solution then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're passing objects as parameter. The following should work fine I think. Please let me know if you're trying to achieve something else.

```
(function(){

var objects = [];

$('button.one').on('click', function(){

  fetchObjects = function() {
    $.post("/fetchObjects")
      .done(function(data){
        objects = data;
        console.log(objects.length);
      });
  }
  fetchObjects()

});

$('button.two').on('click', function(){
  console.log(objects.length);
});

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the code a bit. You have essentially this:

```js
var objects = [];

fetchObjects = function(innerObjects) {
  var data = ['a','b'];
  innerObjects = data;
  console.log(innerObjects.length);
};

fetchObjects(objects);
console.log(objects);
```

(I've changed the other `objects` variable's name just for clarity; the issue is the same even if it had the same name.)

When you call the function, `innerObjects` contains a reference to `objects` so modifying it would change the original array as well. But when you do

```
innerObjects = data;
```

now instead of *modifying* the array you're replacing the reference with something else. `innerObjects` "points" to `data` instead of `objects` and the original variable remains unchanged.

To make it work you'd need to loop through the `data` array (assuming it'll always be an array) and assign the contents to the `objects` reference one by one. This way you'll keep the original reference and modify the original array.

```js
var objects = [];

fetchObjects = function(innerObjects) {
  var data = ['a','b'];
 
  for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
      innerObjects[i] = data[i];
  }
  console.log(innerObjects.length);
};

fetchObjects(objects);
console.log(objects);
```

Or, in your actual code:

```
(function(){

var objects = [];

$('button.one').on('click', function(){

  fetchObjects = function(objects) {
    $.post("/fetchObjects")
      .done(function(data){
        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
          objects[i] = data[i];
        }
        console.log(objects.length);
      });
  }
  fetchObjects(objects)

});

$('button.two').on('click', function(){
  console.log(objects.length);
});

})();
```

Comment: why don't access objects directly from within the method? you don't need to loop nor pass objects as a parameter...

Comment: @acontell The function now works for any array that's passed to it. If you remove the parameter and the loop then it will work for only one hardcoded variable.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. Instead of using `innerObjects` at all, why can't I just say `objects = data`? Because then I would think that I'm replacing the `objects` variable with the stuff from `data`. Why does that not work?

Comment: @Jakobud that would work, thanks to scope, objects is available within the function and you can assign the retrieve data directly to it but not using a parameter as Juhana pointed out

Comment: @Jakobud You need to realize that you have *two* variables called `objects`. When you do `objects = data` you're replacing the *local variable* with `data`. The outer variable is left unchanged.

Comment: That's exactly the point, but if you don't pass it as a parameter and use directly objects, it should work

Comment: @Juhana let me make this question easier. Lets say instead of `objects` being an array, what if it was a boolean? What if I needed to set `objects =  true` within my `.done()` function?

Comment: That would be impossible with the setup you have now because unlike arrays, booleans aren't passed by reference. You'd have to remove the parameter and modify the variable directly in the function.

Comment: I tried that. Seems like it didn't work. I got rid of the `fetchObjects` function completely and just did the `$.post` and tried to access `objects` directly. Doesn't seem to work even though I feel like it should.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/502381 if you're unfamiliar with how object references are passed in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using CoffeeScript and I just realized I think CoffeeScript is re-declaring `objects` as a local var in my button click handler. I think that's the whole problem. Thanks again.